# ATTiny13 Eagle footprint

Tags: pcb, eaglecad, attiny

I am making a small project using ATTiny13 and designing the PCB using Eagle. The problem I have is that the pins of the ATTiny on the PCB seem to be opposite to where it should be (i.e. top/bottom).

I have attached some photos showing 1) the pinout, 2) the schematic, and 3) the holes on the PCB side.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. The pin numbering looks fine to me. Can you clarify what you are asking, what do you think is wrong?

Comment: I don't see any differences there. Pin 1 is in the top left, pin 8 top right.

Comment: I don't see any issue. What is your problem ? The footprint has the same pin numbering as the image of the datasheet you posted. And the signal names on the symbol seems to matches the image of the datasheet. Thus everything seems fine.

Comment: I think your issue is the component side. The footprint is drawn expecting that your component is placed on the Top side of the PCB.
If you think your pins are reversed, do you plan to put the component "behind" the PCB, on the bottom side ? if so, you have to tell eagle to put the component on the bottom side, It will mirror the pins and everything will be correct.

Comment: The PCB image should reflect the bottom side of the PCB while the diagram reflects the top side of the chip. They can't have the pins on the same locations. Basically pin 8 should be on the left and pin 1 on the right because the chip should mounted from the top.

Comment: @Blup1980 I tried mirroring, but then Eagle somehow double the pads - it adds little circle pads in addition to the original pads. I also tried briefly moving the component to the bottom layer but thought this would make it impossible to connect the wires (component and wires both on the bottom layer?)

Comment: @Blup1980 looked at mirroring again and realized it created those little pads before because I had routes already attached to the component. Tried it again, this time deleting all the routes and then mirror and it worked like it should. Thanks!

Comment: The convention in PCB layout programs is that you are looking down on the component side of the board, and are looking through the board to see the solder side (bottom) tracks.  Eagle follows that convention, so the provided footprint is correct.  If you want to place a component on the bottom side of the board, the program should have a command to flip the footprint and move all its features to the appropriate bottom side layers.